# How to get a docker container to the state: dead for debugging?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I need to get some containers to dead state, as I want to check if a script of mine is working. Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by containers to dead state. You can stop containers using "docker stop" or remove containers using "docker rm"

Comment: i mean the result of  `docker ps -a -q -f status=dead`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've asked for a `dead` container.

## TL;DR: This is how to create a dead container

Don't do this at home:

```
ID=$(docker run --name dead-experiment -d -t alpine sh)
docker kill dead-experiment
test "$ID" != "" && chattr +i -R /var/lib/docker/containers/$ID
docker rm -f dead-experiment
```

And voila, docker could not delete the container root directory, so it falls to a `status=dead`:

```
docker ps -a -f status=dead
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE         COMMAND       CREATED             STATUS        PORTS         NAMES
616c2e79b75a        alpine        "sh"          6 minutes ago       Dead                        dead-experiment
```

### Explanation

I've inspected the [source code of docker and saw this state transition](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/cfdf84d5d04c8ee656e5c4ad3db993c258e52674/daemon/delete.go#L106):

```
container.SetDead()
// (...)
if err := system.EnsureRemoveAll(container.Root); err != nil {
    return errors.Wrapf(err, "unable to remove filesystem for %s", container.ID)
}
// (...)
container.SetRemoved()
```

So, if docker cannot remove the container root directory, it remain as dead and does not continue to the Removed state. So I've forced the file permissions to not permit root remove files (`chattr -i`).

PS: to revert the directory permissions do this: `chattr -i -R /var/lib/docker/containers/$ID`

Comment: This my friend is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this as well on my local setup but this is not working, somehow the container is removed and not displayed in the `docker ps -a` output (tho the folder `/var/lib/docker/containers/$ID` is present).

Comment: @Tony do you remember what was this finally?

Comment: No idea, was probably related to a previous Docker version, I've been unable to reproduce this recently.

Answer (score 2):

For docker-1.12+, `instruction` [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) can help you.

> The HEALTHCHECK instruction tells Docker how to test a container to check that it is still working. This can detect cases such as a web server that is stuck in an infinite loop and unable to handle new connections, even though the server process is still running.

For example, we have a Dockerfile to define my own webapp:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

HEALTHCHECK --interval=15s --timeout=3s \
    CMD curl -fs http://localhost:80/ || exit 1
```

> check every five minutes or so that a web-server is able to serve the site’s main page within three seconds.
>   The command’s exit status indicates the health status of the container. The possible values are:
>
> 0: success - the container is healthy and ready for use
>   1: unhealthy - the container is not working correctly
>   2: reserved - do not use this exit code

Then use `docker build` command to build an image:

```
$ docker build -t myapp:v1 .
```

And run a container using this image:

```
$ docker run -d --name healthcheck-demo -p 80:80 myapp:v1
```

check the status of container:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                NAMES
b812c8d6f43a        myapp:v1            "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   healthcheck-demo
```

At the beginning, the status of container is `(health: starting)`; after a while, it changes to be `healthy`:

```
$ docker ps                        
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                NAMES
d2bb640a6036        myapp:v1            "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   2 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   healthcheck-demo
```

It takes `retries consecutive failures` of the health check for the container to be considered `unhealthy`.

You can use your own script to replace the command `curl -fs http://localhost:80/ || exit 1`. What's more, `stdout` and `stderr` of your script can be fetched from `docker inspect` command:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health}}' healthcheck-demo |python -m json.tool
{
    "FailingStreak": 0,
    "Log": [
        {
            "End": "2017-06-09T19:39:58.379906565+08:00",
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r100   612  100   612    0     0  97297      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   99k\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>\n<style>\n    body {\n        width: 35em;\n        margin: 0 auto;\n        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;\n    }\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>\n<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and\nworking. Further configuration is required.</p>\n\n<p>For online documentation and support please refer to\n<a href=\"http://nginx.org/\">nginx.org</a>.<br/>\nCommercial support is available at\n<a href=\"http://nginx.com/\">nginx.com</a>.</p>\n\n<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n",
            "Start": "2017-06-09T19:39:58.229550952+08:00"
        }
    ],
    "Status": "healthy"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a bit, but the idea is to force the container to _die_ in the sense of how to make it dead, not stopped and not exited.

Comment: In my solution, you can use `docker ps -a --filter=health=unhealthy` to filter containers being in `unhealthy` status. I think should not force a container to be dead if you just wan to check if a script of your is working.