# How do I change the state of a Docker container to Dead?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I need to put a Docker container into a Dead state in order to test a script I have. I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455501/how-to-get-a-docker-container-to-the-state-dead-for-debugging) previous post but I can't seem to get it to work (my container always goes to the Exited state).

Is there a way to get a container into a Dead state? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: How is your question different from the one you linked to?  Do you specifically need a Dead container (the answer to that question sounds like it'd be a very unusual case) or is it enough to know that's one of the possible states?

Comment: I specifically need a dead container. The other difference to the question I linked to is that the first answer (Robert's) no longer works. I tried doing what he suggests but the container doesn't change to a Dead state. He linked to the relevant source code but looking at the latest version there are changes. This leads me to believe that the code was fixed so his solution is no longer viable.

Comment: any news on this? I have the same issue with the linked code above.